# C++ arrow to overloaded index ( this->[ ] )

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a simple class, whose index operator I've overloaded:

```
class dgrid{
    double* data; // 1D Array holds 2D data in row-major format
  public:
    const int nx;
    const int ny;
    double* operator[] (const int index) {return &(data[index*nx]);}
}
```

This way `dgrid[x][y]` works as a 2d array, but the data is contiguous in memory.

However, from inside member functions this is a little more clunky, I need to do something like `(*this)[x][y]` which works, but seems smelly, especially when I have sections like:

```
(*this)[i][j] =   (*this)[i+1][j]
                + (*this)[i-1][j]
                + (*this)[i][j+1]
                + (*this)[i][j-1] 
                - 4*(*this)[i][j];
```

Is there a better way to do this? Something like `this->[x][y]` (but this doesn't work). Is using a little function `f(x,y) returns &data[index*nx+ny]` the only option?

Comment: `auto& self = *this; self[i][j] = ...;`

Comment: Or, for the more adventurous type, `(*this)` can be written as `this[0]`...

Comment: More cluncky, but also what you are after: `this->operator[](i)[j]` :)

Comment: Thanks MatiasFG, that's actually the answer I thought I was looking for, even though T.C.'s/Jeffrey's work-around is tidier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could overload ->, but why not simply do:

```
T& that = *this; //or use auto as t.c. suggests

that[i][j] =  that[i+1][j]
            + that[i-1][j]
            + that[i][j+1]
            + that[i][j-1] 
            - 4*that[i][j];
```

That's (pun) at least as readable as this->[][]. No ?